# Proper way to punctuate "oh so slow"

Tags: punctuation

What is the proper way to punctuate a phrase such as "oh so slow" or "oh so pretty"?

I can't find anything in Chicago about it.

I think it would be something like this:
Blah blah blah happened, oh so slow.

Is that correct?

Thank you!

Comment: Shouldn't this go to english.SE?

Answer (score 3):

I think it should be: "Blah. Oh, so slow." Or "Oh, so slow. Blah."

Comment: Depending on the context. If it's used as adjective, it would be *oh-so-slow.*